# Magento - display block but only show when I call it with getChildHtml

Tags: layout, magento, block

I have created a block and I have placed it in to the layout xml and it is showing correctly in my theme. My problem is that I actually don't want it to display until I explicitly call it with getChildHtml('myblock').

My block xml looks like this:

```
<block type="page/html" name="myblock" as="myblock" template="page/html/myblock.phtml"/ >
```

Anyone have a clue how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your block inside another that is neither a `core/list` type nor calls `$this->getChildHtml('')` (note the empty string). That way it will not be shown automatically and you are free to call it at your discretion.